# GCP PubSub java client's Publisher - concurrency not working Multi threaded environement

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to consume messages from Kafka and publish them to Google PubSub. We have 4 Kafka concurrent consumer threads and I injected the Google pubsub client's Publisher. But the Publisher is not working concurrently and becomes a single threaded.

But with the same publisher settings if I run a program outside kafka consumer, I am able publish more than 3000 message per sec.

Here is my Publisher Bean Injected to Kafka consumer. I am using default batchSettings and setting number of threads as 10. I played with different number, but for Kafka thread seems to be forcing Publisher to use just one thread.

Publisher bean code:

```
    ExecutorProvider executorProvider = InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder()
                .setExecutorThreadCount(10)
                .build();
    
    Publisher publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(TopicName.of(projectId, topicId))
                .setExecutorProvider(executorProvider)
                .build();
```

My Kafka Consumer:

```
 

  public class MyKafkaListenerForPubSub {
      
    private final Publisher publisher;
    
      public MyKafkaListenerForPubSub(Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
      }
    
      @KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
      public void processMessage(String content) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
          ByteString messageData = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(content);
          PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(messageData).build();
          ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
      }
    }
```

I tried with my own executor service but It did the same.

I am using the below google pubsub library in a non spring boot app but it uses spring core.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
   <version>1.116.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a simple program to replicate the issue. If we use the Publisher in the executor service it is not able to push the messages.

```
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class GCPPublishExample {
  private static String b64Val = "GCP CREDS BASE 64 value";
  private static String bigMessage = "Some Big Message of size 30 KB";
  private static String projectId = "gcp project Id";
  private static String topicId = "some-topic";

  private static void addShutdownHook(){
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        System.out.println("Program Completed at: " + new Date());
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    addShutdownHook();
    System.out.println("Program Started at: " + new Date());

    final boolean parallel = true;  //false to test without threads
    final int totalRecordsToSend = 100_000; //We should change this number to big if we need
    final int executorSize = 4; //As we have 4 kafka concurrent consumers

    System.out.println("parallel: " + parallel + " totalRecordsToSend: " + totalRecordsToSend + " executorSize: " + executorSize);

    GoogleCredentials creds = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64Val)));

    //Using Default batchingSettings and Default executorProvider
    final Publisher publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(TopicName.of(projectId, topicId))
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(creds))
            .build();

    if(parallel) {
      System.out.println("= PUBLISH IN PARALLEL =");
      ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(executorSize);
      
      IntStream.range(0, totalRecordsToSend).
              forEach(i -> {executorService.execute(new MyGCPPublishRunnable(publisher, bigMessage));});

      executorService.shutdown();
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("= RUNNING IN SEQUENCE =");
      IntStream.range(0, totalRecordsToSend).
              forEach(i -> {publishMessage(publisher, bigMessage);});
    }
  }

  private static void publishMessage(Publisher publisher, String message) {
    try {
      ByteString messageData = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
      PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(messageData).build();
      ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
      //System.out.println("Message sent successfully, messageId: {}" + messageIdFuture.get() + " Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

class MyGCPPublishTask implements Runnable {
  private final Publisher publisher;
  private final String message;

  public MyGCPPublishTask(Publisher publisher, String message) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.message = message;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      ByteString messageData = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(this.message);
      PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(messageData).build();
      ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = this.publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
      //System.out.println("Message sent successfully, messageId: " + messageIdFuture.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "becomes [a] single threaded?" Do you mean you aren't seeing concurrent calls of your `processMessage` function? Do you mean you don't see concurrent requests to Pub/Sub?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn, Yes. It is just using only one GCP connection to send the data and remaining connections sit idle. We could see that using `netstat`. And I see performance is super bad and it is just handling 80 records per sec.

And processMessage is Kafka consumer message, and it takes concurrent requests but Publisher.publish(which is sends message to Google Cloud taking only one thread active)

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn, I have attached a sample class GCPPublishExample, which is demos the Publisher behavior when we use it in single thread model and multi thread environment like java executor service.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn, Sorry for the confusion. The issue is solved. I should have added a callback instead of waiting to get the response messageId.

Answer (score 0):

I had debug statement to log the messageId from GCP that made performance issues as it was waiting for the GCP to response back. After I comment that it worked fine.

LOGGER.debug("Message sent successfully, messageId: {}", messageIdFuture.get());